# Correlating Events in Stream Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I have a number of events that are based on values from devices. They are read in intervals, e.g. every hour. The events are delivered to an Event Hub, which is used as an input to a Stream Analytics (SA) job.

I want to aggregate and calculate an average value in SA. Currently, I aggregate and group the events in SA using an origin id and other properties to create the correct groups and averages. The problem is that the averages are not correct. I think the events a either not complete and/or not correlated correct.

Using a TumblingWindow will produce a number of static windows based on time, but the events I need to aggregate might come across two or more windows.

Using a SlidingWindow, as I understand, will trigger output upon a specific condition and the "look back" for a specified interval. Is this correct? If it is correct, I could attach the same id, like a JobId, to each event that I need aggregated and a value indicating whether it is the last event. When the last event enters SA, the SlidingWindow is triggered and we can "look back" for all the events with the same id. Is this possible?

Are there other options in this case? Basically I need to correlate a number of events based on other characteristics than time.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: These examples might help: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-stream-analytics-query-patterns.md